# Допустимо ли использовать для chmod синтаксис с указанием символов +- перед каждым знаком rwx?

Tags: chmod

Чем отличается синтаксис

```
chmod u=+r+w+x,g=-r-w-x,o=-r-w-x
```

от

```
chmod u=rwx,g=---,o=---
```

Answer (score 1):

Знак `+` говорит о том, что права нужно добавить, а `-` убрать.
Фактически это 2 одинаковые команды. которые выставляют права `700`

> Допустимо ли использовать для chmod синтаксис с указанием символов +-
>   перед каждым знаком rwx?

Допустимо но не имеет смысла указывать это в команде, если указывается знак `=`, то все правила будут заменены на новые, а по умолчанию если права не указаны - значит их нет.

Например, `chmod g+w` добавит для группы права записи, остальные права не тронет, а вот `chmod g=+w` или просто `chmod g=w` даст права группе только на запись, остальные удалит.